# Bootstrap - Custom Content In Dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As the title states, I'm looking to have one single dropdown then have other HTML content in another dropdown submenu, making the dropdown act as a pop out for HTML content. The issue I'm having so far is that once I try just putting a div and code into the `UL` tag for the secondary drop down, it no longer stays visible on hover. Here is my current markup,

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">GAMES &nbsp;<i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
  <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-submenu"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Battlefield 3</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <div>
          <h1 style="color: #333;">Things</h1>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

The markup is to be honest horrendous as of now, but is there an easier way to have custom content in a Bootstrap sub drop down? This way is causing miles upon miles of issues.

Comment: The only valid direct child of `UL` is `LI`. You can put the div inside a list item. This may also solve the issue you're having.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of this way:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">GAMES &nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-submenu"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Battlefield 3</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <div class="custom">
                <h1 style="color: #333;">Things</h1>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This makes the menu more semantically correct and valid... I feel something you might require in the CSS is:

```css
.custom {padding: 0 10px;}
.custom h1 {font-size: 1.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/yEJ3c/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the other children and you're just looking for a rich dropdown, perhaps you want to be using the [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) component instead of the Dropdown component.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Bootstrap 4 - it's now easy to add custom HTML to dropdowns:

```
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Option one</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">Html</div>
                        <div class="col">Content</div>
                        <div class="col">Here</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```